# Why is mega.nz keeping 3.3GB of data in my computer

Tags: google-chrome, internet-security

I am near the end of my free space of my C: drive and chrome said that I should free some space and suggested to show my how much data each site keeps on my machine.
It turns out that a site called mega.nz has 3.3GB on my machine.

chrome shows it when visiting:
chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fmega.nz%2F

I would like to note that I am not familiar with this site and am not using it.
following this discovery I did visit their site and saw that they offer cloud space and I was wandering if somehow they are using my HD to provide storage to other people....

does anybody know if I should remove their data? or how can I see exactly whats in this data???
Is this an indication of some sort of security breach?

Comment: Have you run any malware scans?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the built in microsoft scan which does not show anything special

Comment: That's most probably a serviceworker. See the following answer on how to find out and how to delete it, plus some backgorund: https://superuser.com/a/1632230/714576

Comment: Mega.nz is a reputable company [OK, some of the data they look after for other people isn't, but that's *"not their fault"*]. I very much doubt they would waste time & effort storing a mere 3GB of the many terabytes of storage they have on your drive in any kind of underhand way. It's far more likely to be some kind of data cache or local storage you allowed when you were previously there, even if you've forgotten.

Comment: The answer below should be enough to clarify. Now, if you're worried about ~3GB then not enough free space IS your problem, Keep in mind you should always have at least 10% free space for normal OS functionality.

Comment: thanks @1NN this was educational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cache storage occupied by this website on the chrome browser.

The amount of 3.3 GB is excessive, but can be released by clicking the
button "Clear data" right next to this number.

This will delete the entire cache and cookies data for this website,
so that you will need to login again.

Comment: mega.nz came into being by providing a way to have files in the cloud and have them encrypted.  So if there is 3.3 GB in the cache it means it was required to decrypt the file.  You can avoid this storage being used by NOT visiting mega.nz within a browser and instead use their desktop client (if that is even still around).

Comment: as I mentioned to the best of my knowledge i never visited this site - at least not intentionally - maybe sent there by some popup or something like that.... I think I will follow the advice and just remove it.

Comment: You may have downloaded something hosted at Mega. It's used to share files. @Ramhound Clients for Windows. OSX and Linux are still around and being updated frequently.

Comment: @epeleg - Check your history but it wouldn’t have existed if you didn’t visit the website